# Find the top 2 vendors per country, in each year available in the dataset (Why in my case Qualify clause not work)

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
    o.country_name,
    v.vendor_name,
    EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) AS year,
    ROUND(SUM(o.gmv_local), 2) AS total_gmv
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN Vendors v
    ON o.vendor_id = v.id
GROUP BY
    o.country_name,
    v.vendor_name,
    EXTRACT(year FROM date_local)
--QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_name, EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) ORDER BY total_gmv DESC) <= 2
ORDER BY
    o.country_name DESC,
    total_gmv DESC;
```

Comment: SELECT
    o.country_name,
    v.vendor_name,
    EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) AS year,
    ROUND(SUM(o.gmv_local), 2) AS total_gmv
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN Vendors v
    ON o.vendor_id = v.id
GROUP BY
    o.country_name,
    v.vendor_name,
    EXTRACT(year FROM date_local)
--QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_name, EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) ORDER BY total_gmv DESC) <= 2
ORDER BY
    o.country_name DESC,
    total_gmv DESC;

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.